# Pass to image in Image View in the Same Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to create application for passing the image in image-view in the same Activity while i click on List View Item when i try to it shows the error at code line  The method
 `setImageResource(OurProduct_RAngePojo) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`

Can someone help me please how to do this .Thanks in advanced.

Here is My activity

```
public class Our_ProductRange extends Activity
{
    View selectedImage;

    private ListView productListView;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.our_product_range);

        selectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ProductImage);


        final OurProduct_RAngePojo ourProductRAngePojo[] = new OurProduct_RAngePojo[]
                {
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_build ),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_building_abs ),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_office1),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_office3),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_office4b),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_plant1),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_plant2),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_plant3),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_plant4),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutus_plant5),
                    new OurProduct_RAngePojo(R.drawable.aboutusofficeb),

                };

        OurProductRange_Adapter productadapter = new OurProductRange_Adapter(this, 
                    R.layout.listview_product_item, ourProductRAngePojo);

        productListView = ( ListView)findViewById(R.id.productListView);
        productListView.setAdapter(productadapter);


        productListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //selectedImage.setImageResource(position);
                //final View imageView1 = mUuserGallery.getChildAt(position);
                selectedImage = productListView.getChildAt(position);

            int i=setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position]);

                // selectedImage.setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position]);



            }
        });
```

Here is pojo class

```
public class OurProduct_RAngePojo {
    public int icon;

    public OurProduct_RAngePojo(int icon) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;

    }

    public OurProduct_RAngePojo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Adapter Class

```
  public class OurProductRange_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<OurProduct_RAngePojo>
    {

        Context context; 
        int layoutResourceId;    
        OurProduct_RAngePojo data[] = null;

        public OurProductRange_Adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, OurProduct_RAngePojo[] data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            OurProduct_RAngePojo_Holder holder = null;

            if(row == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new OurProduct_RAngePojo_Holder();
                holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgproductImages);


                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (OurProduct_RAngePojo_Holder)row.getTag();
            }

            OurProduct_RAngePojo aboutus = data[position];

            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(aboutus.icon);

            return row;
        }

        static class OurProduct_RAngePojo_Holder
        {
            ImageView imgIcon;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
selectedImage.setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position].icon);
```

Do the above instead of below code.

```
setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The method " setImageResource(OurProduct_RAngePojo) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}
```

Change

```
int i=setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position]);
// selectedImage.setImageResource(ourProductRAngePojo[position]);
```

To

```
int i=ourProductRAngePojo[position].icon;
selectedImage.setImageResource(i); // needs a resource id
```

From the docs

```
public void setImageResource (int resId)

Added in API level 1
Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.
```